# socket.gethostbyaddr raises error when used on localhost

Tags: python, docker, sockets

Flask is unable to run in Python 3.6 onwards (works fine in Python 2.7-3.5), and the only change I've made recently is installing Docker. I've fully reinstalled Python and all the modules during testing.

The issue is being caused by the `socket` module, when `http` attempts to start a local server. At one point it expects get the hostname of `"127.0.0.1"`, which raises a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Here's an example of the error:

```
# [Python 3] Test against localhost IP (error)
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('127.0.0.1')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 2: invalid start byte

# [Python 3] Test against localhost
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('localhost')
('DESKTOP-XXXXXX', [], ['::1'])

# [Python 2] Output of the command
>>> socket.gethostbyaddr('127.0.0.1')
('xn\x969q8h', ['api.genuine.autodesk.com', 'ase.autodesk.com', 'mpa.autodesk.com', 'sv.symcd.com', 'kubernetes.docker.internal'], ['127.0.0.1'])
```

Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 285, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1052, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1005, in inner
    fd=fd,
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 848, in make_server
    host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 740, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\http\server.py", line 139, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 676, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 2: invalid start byte
```

I guess it's failing to parse the `'xn\x969q8h'` string I see in the Python 2 output, but I've no idea where that's coming from. Running `hostname` in cmd returns `DESKTOP-XXXXX`.

Comment: Edit your [hosts file](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/edit-host-file-windows-10/). Make sure localhost is added as an alias for `127.0.0.1`. Should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just writing up an answer after finding what was causing it, I've absolutely no idea why it only started being an issue a few days ago, but it does appear to be fixed now.

Comment: I do know why actually, docker rewrote my hosts file, but didn't do a good job of it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out many moons ago I thought it'd be funny to create a mapping to [localghost](https://twitter.com/rfreebern/status/1214560971185778693).

When I installed Docker a few days ago, it edited the hosts file, and in the process, changed `xn--9q8h` to `xn–9q8h`. The `socket` module was still attempting to interpret that as unicode, but was failing due it being invalid.

I'll make a bug report on both Python and Docker as it's certainly not the intended behaviour.